# Find out if a session is running under `su`

Tags: su

I'm trying to check whether the current shell session is running within a `su` login session.

What's the best way to test this condition?

Comment: Do you really care if the login was through su or do you want to know if the current user is root?

Comment: No, don't care who the user is, just if it's in a su subshell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

look into the `logname` command.  logname will print the username of the user who logged into the controlling terminal as provided by the utmp log.

```
tk-mbp:~ tkennedy$ id -g -rn
staff
tk-mbp:~ tkennedy$ id -u -rn
tkennedy
tk-mbp:~ tkennedy$ logname
tkennedy
tk-mbp:~ tkennedy$ su -
Password:
tk-mbp:~ root# id -g -rn
wheel
tk-mbp:~ root# id -u -rn
root
tk-mbp:~ root# logname
tkennedy
```

This example if from Mac OS X, so the use of the `id` command may differ to other OSes, however, the use of logname is consistent between Mac OS X, Linux, and Solaris, which are all the OSes I have available to night to test with.

By using logname, you can assume that if the user returned by the `id` command is **not** the same as the user returned by `logname`, then the current shell session is being run under su, or sudo, or some other tool that allows for privilege change in a shell.

Comment: These are standard environment variables as well, so `[[ if $LOGNAME != $USER ]]` works perfectly.

Comment: @AndrewVit: I thought so too, but when I execute `echo "$USER / $LOGNAME / $(logname)"` inside `sudo -i` on my Mac OS X, I get: `root / root / janmoesen`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to test whether the current shell was executed by `su`:

```
[ "$(ps -o comm= $PPID)" = "su" ]
```

If you want to test whether the user called `su` since logging in, then on many (but not all) systems you can compare `LOGNAME` (normally set at the initial login) with `USER` or `id -un` (which identifies the current user). Note that `LOGNAME` is trivially spoofable (it's an environment variable). But then, so are other solutions (for example `ln -s /bin/su ~/sh; ~/sh` will hide the `su` from any solution based on process names).

Comment: My question was just for a shell prompt so I don't need anything super robust. That test works well. Nice trick using the -o option to hide the header!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution I wired up:

```
pstree -p $$ | 
grep -oP '[r]oot su .*(\w+)' |
sed -n -E 's/.* ([[:alnum:]]+)$/\1/p'`
```

**pstree** with the -p flag lists the ancestry tree of the current shell process PID ($$)

**grep** finds lines containing "root su" (I'm using the [r] trick to avoid returning the grep process itself)

**sed** cleans up the result and prints just the current username at the end of the line. (It would be more helpful if it would print the user of the parent process though.)